# Google Maps infoWindow without marker?

Tags: maps, infowindow

According to the documention a marker is optional with an infoWindow, so how is this achieved please? I have tried *infowindow.open(map)* and *infowindow.open(map,null)* but both produce nothing.

Comment: What do you want and and what have you tried, post here the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`infowindow.open(map)` makes no sense since you need to specify the position where the infowindow should open, also it has a tapered stem which specifies the location where it should point.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows) of Infowindows- *InfoWindows may be attached to either Marker objects (in which case their position is based on the marker's location) or on the map itself at a specified LatLng.*

So if you donot want the marker to open the infowindow, use the map click event-

```
var iwindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event)
    {
         iwindow.setContent(event.latLng.lat()+","+event.latLng.lng());
         iwindow.open(map,this); 
         iwindow.open(map,this);
    });
```

And to close a InfowWindow- `infowindow.setMap(null);`

Hope that cleared your doubts.

Comment: Welcome. Plz consider to mark the answer by clicking on the tick mark beside the solution :)

Answer (score 9):

If the position is set, there is no problem showing the info window

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: {lat: 55.6761, lng: 12.5683},
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: "Copenhagen"
});
infowindow.setPosition({lat: 55.6761, lng: 12.5683});
infowindow.open(map);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the api has changed, it is not possible to set position on info window any more. the solution i found is to add a marker to the map with visibility false:

```
this.map.addMarker({
        position: {
          'lat': sites[0].latitude,
          'lng': sites[0].longitude
        },
        // setting visible false since the icon will be the poi icon
        visible: false
      }).then((marker: Marker) => {

        this.htmInfoWindow.open(marker);
      });
```