# How can I add an Infowindow to a google map without a marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I add an infowindow to a map without a marker where I can specify the position (latlng) manually.
There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097888/google-maps-infowindow-without-marker) which uses the click location, but I want to specify it myself. So far, I tried:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "You start here",
    position: document.getElementById('start').value
  });
```

inside the  map initialization function and used this code:

```
  infowindow.open(map, new google.maps.LatLng(6.473500, 81.236577));
```

inside the listener but it didn't work. An error comes up saying it cannot read the latlng given to open the infowindow.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the position, either with a `google.maps.Marker` object in the open call, or if you don't have a marker, setting the position directly.  This works:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "You start here",
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(6.473500, 81.236577)
});
infowindow.open(map);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Ltys3aht/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function loadMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.473500, 81.236577)
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "You start here",
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(6.473500, 81.236577)
  });
  infowindow.open(map);
}
window.onload = loadMap();
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```