# Google Maps v2: launch custom infowindow without using a marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

My question is regarding the java way of achieving this: [Google Maps infoWindow without marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097888/google-maps-infowindow-without-marker)

Is it possible to launch a custom info window in v2 without using a marker? Which event should I use to detect a long press on the map and how can I launch an InfoWindow?

Here is what I want to achieve.

[image]

I need to be able to get the location from the place, so I can add the marker to that position, whenever an icon from the custom view is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to launch a custom info window in v2 without using a
>   marker?

It isn't, but you can create a transparent marker and show the `InfoWindow` on it.
To make it transparent, use a transparent resource or use `marker.setAlpha(0.0f)`.

> Which event should I use to detect a long press on the map?

You can use the method [`GoogleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnMapLongClickListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener)).

> How can I launch an InfoWindow?

You have to add a `Marker` and call `showInfoWindow()` method on it.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger an event when one of the icons is clicked? I guess not: " Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events"